# How to return an ArrayList of objects in MongoDB and Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven

I have a method in my DAO which looks like this

**ProductDao.java**

```
public List<Document> getAllProducts() {
    return mongoCollection.find().into(new ArrayList<Document>());
}
```

What I would like instead is

```
//return a list of Product instead of Document
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    return mongoCollection.find().into(new ArrayList<Product>());
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few java libs that can help you with it:

Morhpia - http://code.google.com/p/morphia/

Spring Data for MongoDB - http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb

Also, you can do something like:

```
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    DBCursor cur = mongoCollection.find();
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    while(cur.hasNext()) {
        products.add(cur.next());
    }
    return products;
}
```

Comment: Keen on trying out Morphia. Looks promising. Is it a subproject of MongoDB ?

Comment: Yes it is a sub project, Morphia is built on top of the original mongodb java driver. Its like a wrapper around it.

Comment: The problem with this is that it opens a connection every time the method is called, do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

look into `MongoJack`.

Mongojack maps Java objects to MongoDB documents. Based on the Jackson JSON mapper, Mongojack allows you to easily handle your mongo documents as POJOs